# formatting the key value of a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like the change the format of the key value of a dictionary.

Something like

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictcatalogue = new Dictionary<string,string>();

dictCatalogue = dictCatalogue.Select(t => t.Key.ToString().ToLower() + "-ns").ToDictionary();
```

How can I alter the key of my dictionary without affecting the value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track with creating a new dictionary:

```
dictcatalogue = dictcatalogue.ToDictionary
       (t => t.Key.ToString().ToLower() + "-ns", t => t.Value);
```

Comment: this works but it creates a new object (Dictionary) .For large dictionary can throw memory overflow exception

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the key of an existing dictionary entry. You'll have to remove/add using a new key.

what do you need to do? perhaps we can suggest a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to consider stuartd's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16299065/674700) as the right solution. Still, if you are interested in a way to work with your dictionary by ignoring the case sensitivity and not creating a new dictionary, check out the following code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var searchedTerm = "test2-ns";
        Dictionary<string, string> dictCatalogue = 
            new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        dictCatalogue.Add("test1", "value1");
        dictCatalogue.Add("Test2", "value2");

        // looking for the key with removed "-ns" suffix
        var value = dictCatalogue[searchedTerm
            .Substring(0, searchedTerm.Length - 3)];

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

// Output
value2
```